# Detect second click on a segment

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

According to the documentation, the event which should related to `UISegmentedControl` is value changed. Assuming I have a segmented control with previous and next, in my case I should be able to click next more than one time, the default behaviour of `UISegmentedControl` will not recognize the successif second click on same segment. SO how to deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `momentary` property of your UISegmentedControl to `TRUE`.

You can do that in code or in Interface Builder (there is a checkbox in the Attributes Inspector).

Comment: Nice to meet you `momentary` :D

Comment: I tried momentary property, its working good... but it removed blue background.. How can i get blue background..