# UISegmentedControl: how to detect click on current segment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

is there a way to detect second click on a segment in UISegmentedControl? I found:

[Detect second click on a segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328993/detect-second-click-on-a-segment)

however, it is stated that:

> If you set a segmented control to have a momentary style, a segment doesn’t show itself as selected (blue background) when the user touches it. The disclosure button is always momentary and doesn’t affect the actual selection.

Is there a way to detect second click **as well as** trigger the selection action and show the segment as selected?

If there is no straight forward way to do it, what I was thinking, is that I first have the `momentary` flag set to `YES`, then upon each click, manually update the selection state, but then I also need to update/deselect other segments.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to have a custom subclass of UISegmentedControl and check it yourself like this.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    current = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    if (current == self.selectedSegmentIndex)
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

I had an other solution all in touchesBegan, but it's not working anymore in iOS 7. There is also other solution on Stack Overflow that are not working in iOS 6 and greater.

Comment: Most of the solutions I've tried so far would trigget the selection event two times, this works perfectly on iOS 7. You are the best, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To make a particular segment click-able again is not possible, but you can reset the whole segmentControl using UISegmentedControlNoSegment.

```
[self.segmentCtrlOutlet setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
```

what you have to do is put the above code in the place where that code executes when you click on a particular segment of UISegmentedControl.

for eg. In my project when I click on a segment, UIPopoverController opens up and inside it I have UIPicker, so I use the above code in UIPicker delegate method "didSelectRow"

Comment: Isn't this the same as making the control momentary? I don't think it solves the question, since the OP wants to detect a click on a segment that is already selected. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618586-ismomentary